# E-mail address spoofing by spammers - how to block it in Postfix/Spamassassin?

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin

I run a Postfix mail server using Spamassassin as after-queue filter.

It works quite well, but sometimes I get spam from the network that has correct `MAIL FROM:` address, but also contains, in `DATA:` section, different forged address  `something <at> mydomain.com`.

Most e-mail client programs, including Thunderbird and Outlook, displays it using the second ( forged ) address.

I would like to block such messages automatically, but I can't do it using `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`  ( forged address resides in `DATA:` section ).

It also have nothing to do with SPF since `MAIL FROM:` ( envelope sender ) address may be correct according to SPF.

Then how can I do it using Postfix settings or Spamassassin rules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix doesn't care about the mail content. `$smtpd_recipient_restrictions` look at the `envelope-from`, not at the `From:` header in the mail, and you can't use `header_checks` for this:

> Message headers added by the **cleanup**(8) daemon itself are excluded from inspection.  Examples  of such message headers are **From:**, **To:**, **Message-ID:**, **Date:**.

Not to mention that it's unwise to block messages where the `From:` header differs from the `envelope-from`. Mailing lists for instance will use the mailing list address (or a VERP address) in the envelope, while the original `From:` address will remain in the body.